# How to create a row of working days? Seems to be working only for columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to create a calendar with days on columns and people on rows.
I would make a sheet per month.

I tried putting the start date 01/month/year in an hidden sheet A1 and then using the following:

```
=WORKDAY(Hidden!$A$1;1)
```

Then I would drag along the row this formula, but it does not work: it just repeats the same number.

The only way I could make this work was by writting explicitely the start date in my sheet and using this formula by dragging along the column, but this would lead to the days on the rows and the people on the columns which is the opposite I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1 in your formula is a constant so it doesn't change as you drag right.

You need something that will change Like the `COLUMN()` function which returns the column number.

In A1 then `=WORKDAY(Hidden!$A$1;COLUMN())`